# React Native + XCode : Could Not Connect to Development Server

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm getting the following when trying to start up a basic app in XCode. I tried setting the port to a different one but that didn't work. This happens when I try to run by hitting the play button in XCode.

[image: error description]

When I try running the app from the command line and inside my project directory, I don't get an error and everything seems to work smoother for the most part. The app shows the splash screen for a couple seconds and then gives me an error then it quit unexpectedly.

Comment: what version of RN? What in AppDelegate.m? Is node server running?

Comment: Close all of your terminal, and reload your app again, have a try.

Comment: I changed the localhost to 5000 instead of the default and this seemed to work. Thanks for your help everyone!